# Update on a table changes a field in another table

Tags: mysql, jdbc, bitnami

I'm working on a web application that handles some orders.

I have two tables defined as

```
CREATE TABLE sent_orders (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  code VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  date_open TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  state VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  direction VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) )


CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  state_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  date_open TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  date_processed TIMESTAMP NULL,
  date_closed TIMESTAMP NULL,
  sent_order_id INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
  INDEX fk_orders_3_idx (state_id ASC) ,
  INDEX fk_orders_5_idx (sent_order_id ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_orders_1
    FOREIGN KEY (state_id)
    REFERENCES order_states (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_orders_2
    FOREIGN KEY (sent_order_id)
    REFERENCES sent_orders (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

The order processing is made of two steps in different times:

1. an order is inserted with a specific date_open and null sent_order_id with

   ```
   insert into orders (...,date_open,..) values(...,?,...)
   ```
2. a sent_order is inserted with a different date_open

   ```
   insert into sent_orders (...,date_open,..) values(...,?,...)
   ```
3. an update is made on the orders table to add the foreign key on the sent_orders

   ```
   update orders set sent_order_id = ? where id = ?
   ```

The problem is that when I run the update on the orders table the orders.date_open field gets updated with the current date.

Another strange thing is that to debug the problem I added a second date field 'date_open2' on the orders table and then I ran a massive update as:

```
alter table orders add date_open2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL;
update orders set date_open2 = date_open;
```

And now when I run

```
select date_open,date_open2,id,sent_order_id from orders
```

what I have is something like:

```
date_open               date_open2              id          sent_order_id
2015-11-17 23:35:14.0   2015-11-17 23:34:27.0   8654        678
```

Where the date_open2 is the original date_open, but it should be equal to the date_open field! It means that the update query got the right date value, but when I select it, it is wrong.

Mysql instance:

- bitnami wampstack-5.4.25-0 with MySQL Server 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TIMESTAMP` columns are being automatically updated as described in

[11.3.5 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Specifically

> With neither DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP nor ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, it is the same as specifying both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

It sounds like you'll either want to modify the auto-update behaviour of your `TIMESTAMP` columns or use `DATETIME` columns instead.